# convert datetime stamp of six hexadecimal octets using python

Tags: python

I need to convert a date time stamp that consists of six hexadecimal octets using python and can not seem to find an easy way to do so.  I am parsing a number of entries from some anti-virus logs and need to covert the date time value to something that looks like a regular date.

For example: 200A13080122 should translate to "November 19, 2002, 8:01:34 AM"

This is the format I have to work with:

The timestamp consists of six hexadecimal octets. They represent the following:
First octet: Number of years since 1970
Second octet: Month, where January = 0
Third octet: Day
Fourth octet: Hour
Fifth octet: Minute
Sixth octet: Second
For example, 200A13080122 represents November 19, 2002, 8:01:34 AM.

Appreciate any help,

Comment: Thanks to everyone for all the great answers

Answer (score 2):

```
import binascii, calendar
Y,M,D,h,m,s = map(ord, binascii.a2b_hex("200A13080122"))
ampm = "AM"
if h >= 12:
    h = h-12
    ampm = "PM"
if h == 0:
    h = 12
print "%s %d, %d, %d:%d:%d %s" % (calendar.month_name[M+1], D, 1970+Y, 
                                  h, m, s, ampm)
```

Comment: Great answer, just add the zero-padding to hours, minutes and seconds.

Answer (score 0):

```
import datetime
def h(i):
    return int(i,16)
s = '200A13080122'
date = datetime.datetime(h(s[0:2]) + 1970, h(s[2:4]) + 1, h(s[4:6]), h(s[6:8]), h(s[8:10]), h(s[10:12]))
```

Since you say you need to convert to "something that looks like a regular date", I take the liberty of displaying it this way...

Comment: Ahh, no one noticed my h(i) function welcoming the new user and inviting him to "return" at another "datetime"...

Answer (score 0):

```
import datetime
dt = "200A13080122"
y, M, d, h, m, s = (int(o[0]+o[1], 16) for o in zip(dt[::2],dt[1::2]))
date = datetime.datetime(y+1970, M+1, d, h, m, s)
print date.strftime("%B %d, %Y, %I:%M:%S %p")
```

Comment: you have two variables called 'm'.

Comment: I just noticed that, too. Was wondering why I'm getting February instead of November. Duh.

Comment: Thank you for all your answers

Answer (score 0):

```
import time
ts = 0x200A13080122
struct_time = ((ts >> 40) + 1970, (ts >> 32 & 0xFF) + 1, ts >> 24 & 0xFF, ts >> 16 & 0xFF, ts >> 8 & 0xFF, ts & 0xFF, 0, 0, 0)
print time.strftime("%B %d, %Y, %I:%M:%S %p", struct_time)
# November 19, 2002, 08:01:34 AM
```

There might be a better way to get each octet.